# Swift Storyboard UITableView Static Cells - UIToolBar appears when scrolling down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitoolbar

Looking for some clarification on why when using a UITableView with Static Cells that when scrolling down a UIToolBar will appear and cut off content. The UIToolBar does not appear when using reusable cells and scrolling. I have tried looking around for some answers to maybe there is some default use for this since this does appear by default but no luck so far.

I am looking to see how I can remove this UIToolBar so it does not appear and cut off content since it is not necessary.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just need to go to your Navigation Controller and uncheck "Shows Toolbar"

[image]